# How do you enable generic return types in `@Query`-annotated repository methods?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jpql

So Spring comes with the option to write repository queries that return one of multiple projection interfaces by allowing to pass the Interface down to the repository.

E.g.

```kotlin
@Repository
interface FooRepository : ReadOnlyRepository<Foo, Int> {
    fun <T> findByBarId(barId: Int, type: Class<T>): List<T>
}
```

I now need to write a query where it's rather cumbersome to derive it by name, so I want to use the `@Query` annotation. But I also want to be able to use projection interfaces.

How do I do that?
The naive attempt,

```kotlin
@Repository
interface FooRepository : ReadOnlyRepository<Foo, Int> {
    fun <T> findByBarId(barId: Int, type: Class<T>): List<T>


    @Query("""
        SELECT :T
           FROM Foo f
           WHERE f.barId = :barId AND ...
    """)
    fun <T> findByBarIdWhereSomeComplicatedCondition(@Param("barId") barId: Int, @Param("T") type: Class<T>): List<T>
}
```

fails with

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Query argument T not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument T not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.
```

and I can't seem to find anything on [the relevant docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic).

Comment: It's better to use Object as return type

Comment: Can you provide structure data designed for Model `Foo`. What's purpose when you use generic here? :)

Comment: @AbinashGhosh That's a bold claim -- and one I disagree with. Could you explain why you think that?

Comment: @NguaCon Please have a look at Example 88 of the docs linked in the question. :) The idea here is that `Foo` is a rather large table and that we can use one of multiple selection interfaces to fetch just as much data from the table as is necessary to answer the query.

Comment: @User1291 thanks, I see. :)

Comment: I think not impossible when using it. You can read jira issue of Spring JPA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1003 :D